# Modern way of accessing AST in Java

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree

What is the state-of-the-art way of accessing and modifying an AST in Java? I only found old examples on that with a lot of deprecated code.
I found several descriptions and also I have an unclear view of how tools like antlr play into this whole concept.
Maybe I should add that I want to parse an existing program, not to write an AST from scratch.

What I want to do with this AST is to transform it so that is easily possible to extract business rules for a rules engine. Maybe you have a good approach on that idea.

Comment: @Mureinik: he asked what the state of the art was.  That's a perfectly fine question.  What he has done is irrelevant wrt to that question.

Comment: @dasLort: I suspect your question will get closed.  SO zealots seem to hate answers asking about tools and technology.  See my bio if you want to know more.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what the Java community largely uses are things like the Eclipse AST interface (or access to the AST as offered by the Java compiler).  This is basically tree nodes and lots of procedural computations to test node types and walk up and down trees.  I don't think that is "state of the art" in general.  Eclipse I think does offer some information how identifiers are tied to definitions ("name resolution").

The ANTLR parsers will help you build ASTs, and I'm sure there's a complete Java front for ANTLR that does that already, check their site.   I think tree walking is the same as it is for the Eclipse AST.   I don't think ANTLR's front end offers name resolution.

Better schemes involve [attribute grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute_grammar), which allow you to build analyzers using dataflow computations across tree nodes.  You can find Java implementations in [Silver](http://aszt.inf.elte.hu/~gsd/s/cikkek/gener/wyk07attribute.pdf) and [JastAdd](http://jastadd.org). These don't seem to be widely known in the Java community.   JastAdd offers access to name resolution as well as data flow information, both of which IMHO are needed to do any interesting code analyses.

Pattern directed schemes are better yet; you describe syntax fragments of interest and corresponding actions. (Attribute grammars are kind of like pattern directed schemes limited to single tree nodes; pattern directed schemes operate on sets of tree nodes whose structure you personnally don't have to know).   [Program transformation systems (PTS) such as Stratego, DMS, and TXL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation) offer these.  However none of these are coded *in* Java.  I'm pretty sure Stratego and TXL have full Java grammars and trees off the shelf, but nothing beyond that.  DMS offers attribute grammars, name resolution, flow analysis, rewrites on trees using patterns, and even data flow based pattern matchers, for a variety of languages including Java.

You need as much analysis information as you can get to support "business rule extraction".   If you think that is going to be *easy*, you're in for a rude surprise. While the code analysis capability is a necessary condition, to recognize business rules you need knowledge from outside the system as to the business vocabulary and actions of interest, and how they are mapped onto the code.  The code doesn't contain that information.

EDIT: based on discussion in comments, OP suggests a semiautomated process implying that a person brings this extra knowledge to the process; I quite agree that is necessary.  He may find this [presentation on extracting business rules](http://semanticdesigns.com/Company/Publications/ExtractingBusinessRules.pdf) helpful to see why, and what one might do about that.

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer. No, I am not expecting the business rules to be extracted easily. Instead, I expect it to be manual work 95% of the time. That's why I need some sort of intermediate AST which allows to check (as in checkbox) if sth is a business rule or not. I'm not sure which one of the many tools fits the best here. First, this shall be implemented for Java Code, but later if should be possible to transform every language into this intermediate form. Is the "standard Java AST" sufficient for that purpose? I doubt other languages can fit into that concept

Comment: Good, we agree there has to be a human in the loop doing significant work. If there is a business rule in the code, there is no reason to believe it corresponds to a specific AST node. Any interesting concept (business rule or technology implementation) in a program is more likely to be scattered about across many ASTs, some in one method, some in another.  So your "checkbox" has to be over regions of code.  You need precise analysis to enable that human to navigate the code effectively. ...

Comment: You won't find a single representation for all programs; people have been looking for 50 years. Our DMS tool is a reaction to that; it instead provides as much common infrastructure as possible.